# Show/hide not working for choice fields if conditioned by calculated fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, form, conditional

In Sharepoint Online, in the New Item form I have a couple of choice fields that should be shown/hidden depending on the values of other fields.

If these fields are text fields, the conditions work and choice fields are shown correctly in the form. If the fields are calculated fields, the choice fields are not shown (so the conditional formulas do not seem to work correctly).

I have done several experiments, changing the name of all the fields, and I am also sure that the names I have used are the real "internal" names.
Could you kindly help me?
Thank you in advance,
Alberto

Comment: could you please share your conditional formulas that you are using to show hide

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide#unsupported-column-types-in-conditional-formulas), calculated columns is unsupported column types in conditional formulas.

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.